# why my code throws this exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

My servlet is supposed to redirect me to a welcome.jsp page if the authentification succeed and to a fail.jsp if not.

```
user = request.getParameter("name");
pass = request.getParameter("pass");
String q = "select * from users where user=" + user
        + " and  password=" + pass + "";
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(q);
String username = null;
String password = null;

while (rs.next()) {
    username = rs.getString(2);
    password = rs.getString(3);

}
if (username.equals(user) && password.equals(pass)) { // <-- Here is line 56
    response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");

} else {
    response.sendRedirect("Fail.jsp");
}
```

.

```
Avertissement:   StandardWrapperValve[LoginServlet]:Servlet.service() for servlet LoginServlet threw exception
               java.lang.NullPointerException
               at com.DemoLogin.LoginServlet.service(LoginServlet.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at  org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @JohnnySparow. No your problem is not different. And when you understand why, you will have become a better coder.

Comment: @JohnnySparow. Good. Small steps is the best way to get where you are going. Glad to see you are on the right track.

Comment: @JohnnySparrow. It is. We all started in pretty much the same place at one time or another. Every time you spend 7 hours banging your head against the wall and then get the solution a few days (or weeks) later, you've made progress. Doesn't seem that way now, but you'll have learned a lot more than just how not to make this one specific mistake. Kudos just for keeping at it in the face of all that.

Comment: This is not JSP/Servlet specific. This is just basic Java. Every compiler error and exception of `java.lang.*` package such as `java.lang.NullPointerException` coming from own code is just basic Java. Most likely it's too early to dive into JSP/Servlets and you'd better take a step back and work through the basic Java examples first (Oracle, OCP, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a equals in a String that is null, if the query returns 0 elements, both username and password are null, thus giving a nullpointer.

```
if(username==null || password==null){

          response.sendRedirect("Fail.jsp");
          return;
}
if (username!=null && username.equals(user)&& password.equals(pass))
        {
            response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");
          return;

        }
        else {
          response.sendRedirect("Fail.jsp");
          return;
        }
```

Also you should use a return; after the redirects just to be sure, and building a dao would also help, having the sql code in the servlet code will become a mess in the long run

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
if(rs.next())
    {
       response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");

    }        
    else {
      response.sendRedirect("Fail.jsp");
    }
```

If username and password is correct then `rs.next()` will be true, because you query will retrieve one row from the database. So you can redirect to the user in `Welcome.jsp`. Else the user provided wrong username or password, so you can redirect to the user `Fail.jsp`.

But in your approach if user provides wrong username or password then you definitely will get a `NullPointerException` as you do not take care about null check properly.

One important point while you are using `Connection` or `Statement` or `ResultSet` , you should properly take care about opening and closing of these.

Comment: Yes you're right.. that's clever!!! but i'm facing a problem with the jdbc connector and i don't know the reason why. It shows me this :                                          Avertissement:   The web application [/WebApplication5] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Infos:   visiting unvisited references

Comment: You did not close Connection or Statement or ResultSet. Could please update your code and try.

Comment: Yes i did modified my code. Now i don't get errors but i always got redirected to fail.jsp even when i type the right username and password.

Comment: In the query you have to put this user=' "+user+" ' instead of   user=" + user + " . I used your query in the first place and it shows me error while login

Comment: Right. So are you able to login now?

Comment: Now yes!!!! well we have to write this :                                               if(rs.next()) {
    username = rs.getString(2);
    password = rs.getString(3);
    response.sendRedirect("Welcome.jsp");
} 
                else {
                  response.sendRedirect("Fail.jsp");
                }

Comment: Great. But if you are not doing anything with username and password, then you can skip get those values from resultset.